# What Voltage/Current Levels Can I Send Into the Microphone Input on a Mobile Phone?

Tags: voltage, audio, rs232, mobile

I have a device that is sending 9600baud using only Tx, Rx, and Gnd.
I am not sure, but I think the voltage is either the 3v or 5v level.

I want to receive that serial data on my mobile phone.

I have found AFSK code for decoding on the mobile phone, however I am concerned about sending the 3 or 5 volts into the microphone circuit.

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to the RS-232 voltages in order to step them down properly for the microphone circuit on the phone?

Comment: You say you have FSK code for decoding, but it doesn't sound like you have anything in place to convert the RS232 to FSK, am I understanding that right?

Comment: Perhaps my question should be "How can I make my mobile phone headset jack into a serial port to send/receive RS-232?"

Comment: @Kellenjb - I have now followed links to your other well-written answers, and I believe I should be referencing AFSK or Audio Frequency Shift Keying - as is used in old telephone modems.

Comment: @Kellenjb You are correct, and I am looking for something to translate the RS-232 signals to AFSK to input to the audio jack on the mobile phone.  I am currently investigating the audio jack modem on the SparkFun site here: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10331 - except I am not sure  what is passing over the FSK in and out ports of this board.  Any insight on that?

Comment: Some mobiles actually have a serial port in the accessory connector - it might be worth researching this possibility.

Comment: @arrocharJames can you provide a specification sheet for the phone.

Comment: @CyberMen I don't have such a sheet, nor do I know where to get one.  Any clues?

Comment: @arrocharJames what kind of phone are you using. Start from there.

Comment: can you please share the afsk code so that i can get a better idea to explain things.I have done my projects on this area that have won acclamation from the IIT's

Comment: The idea comes from this product from SparkFun: Audio Jack Modem for iPhone and Android, see: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Microphone inputs on phones are designed to be compatible with electret microphones which produce very small ac voltages.  A signal at about 5mV peak to peak should work.  The phone may be looking for a DC load to detect the presence of a mic - so have a 1k dc impedance to gnd. Be careful, iPhones and Android phones have different pin outs on the headphone jack.
2. RS232 signals are not dc balanced and therefore cannot be captured properly by an audio input.  That is why the serial data must be FSK modulated (or similar algorithm) or Manchester encoded.
3. Some (or most?) phones have a ~100Hz high pass filter on the input which not only blocks dc but also causes phase distortion so that an input square wave will not look much like a square wave after capture.

Answer (score -3):

For mobile applications, 3V voltage level signaling is OK instead of 5V, you may use 3V without any doubt, or you may try 5V you will not get any error or bad response as all mobiles applications are designed for 3 to 5 V signaling

Comment: Have you considered the OP was talking about *audio* levels? And have you tried yourself what you've suggested? (without frying your audio input circuitry of course.)